# Is magnanimity the right word for courage, insight and willingness to overlook or forgive?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Definitions of *magnanimous* in some of the most authoritative dictionaries:

Oxford Dictionaries Online:

> Generous or forgiving, especially towards a rival or less powerful person.

Dictionary.com (Random House Dictionary):

> 1. Generous in forgiving an insult or injury; free from petty resentfulness or vindictiveness.
> 2. High-minded; noble.
> 3. Proceeding from or revealing generosity or nobility of mind, character, etc.

American Heritage Dictionary:

> Highly moral, especially in showing kindness or forgiveness, as in overlooking insults or not seeking revenge.

And the Wikipedia entry for *magnanimity*:

> The virtue of being great of mind and heart. It encompasses, usually, a refusal to be petty, a willingness to face danger, and actions for noble purposes. Its antithesis is pusillanimity.

All of the dictionaries define *magnanimous* as either generous, forgiving or all-encompassing moral (which may include courageous). Only the Wikipedia article has the explicit definition of courage in *magnanimity*.

My question is: is magnanimity the right word for courage, insight and willingness to overlook, accept or forgive? I am looking for a single word or two words (nouns) that expresses the same meanings as courage, insight and willingness to overlook or forgive combined.

Comment: A great heart..

Comment: I am not looking for some unspecific general word like "a great heart".

Comment: try "greathearted."

Comment: "Insight" strikes me as a bit of an outlier in your list of three qualities. Insight into what? Insight seems like less of a matter of "heart" and more a matter of "mind." I'd love to see a word that fits your description, but in my own search I can't seem wrap the mental acuity of "insight" up with "courage" and "forgiveness."

Comment: @RustyTuba I am doing a translation of `膽識` (courage + insight) and `胸襟` (willingness to overlook, accept, forgive, etc). Magnanimity seem to have the meaning of both courage and willingness to overlook, accept, forgive, etc, so I was wondering if I could translate the two Chinese words into one English word.

Comment: I wondered if this were a case of translation. It's a tricky business, and Chinese (as well as Japanese and Korean, by way of Chinese) has a vast number of words for emotions and personal qualities that are not perfectly translatable. Consider 情 or the classical definition of 恨.

Comment: I have seen other translations of 膽識, including "have the guts" to do something or "have gall". Even "courage" + "sense of humor."

Comment: @RustyTuba But magnanimity seems to be the word that comes closest. I just want to know if it is clear to an English speaker when I say a person possesses magnanimity, that person possesses courage, insight and willingness to accept and overlook (and ideally not less and not more). "Sense of humor": maybe in a limited set of contexts, but no in general (that is my understanding).

Comment: I honestly think "magnanimity" is the closest you'll come. It has all the right connotations. And I wish we had more opportunity to use it!

Comment: I don't make the ***courage*** connection myself. It's in OED's second definition: *Great in courage; nobly brave or valiant. Of a quality, action, etc.: proceeding from or manifesting great courage. **Obsolete***. The first (still current) definition is *generous in feeling or conduct; superior to petty resentment or jealousy,* wherein it adds *Also **archaic**: great or noble in spirit, ambition, or purpose.* The Wikipedia article may be misleading for current use (perhaps it's like that to help decipher old texts).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't see that second definition. Is it in the subscribed version of OED only?

Comment: @Gao Weiwei: I'm looking at the subscriber-only *full* OED, yes. And given that second definition is obsolete, it doesn't surprise me that they haven't included it in the cut-down free version online.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you write what you've said as an answer, I would accept it. So it looks like it's up to me if I want to risk omitting the word *courage* as *magnanimity* might not also mean *courage* to many people nowadays.

Comment: Where is the reference to courage in the Wikipedia quotation? Even the [full article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnanimity) only makes a passing reference to it – and not as part of the definition.

Comment: @ErikKowal What I meant was the Wikipedia article singled out `a willingness to face danger`, which I took as courage. Magnanimity usually *encompasses* courage, and as FumbleFingers said, OED does give an obsolete definition of *nobly brave or valiant* for *magnanimous*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my earlier comment, I don't make the "courage" connection myself, but it's in OED's second definition for **magnanimous**...

> *Great in courage; nobly brave or valiant.
>
>    Of a quality, action, etc.: proceeding from or manifesting great courage.
>
>   **Obsolete***

The first (still current) definition is *generous in feeling or conduct; superior to petty resentment or jealousy,* wherein it adds *Also **archaic:** great or noble in spirit, ambition, or purpose.* I think the Wikipedia article is misleading for *current* usage, but perhaps it's biased to deciphering old texts.

---

For the record, note that Wikipedia says *"the antithesis [of **magnanimity**] is [**pusillanimity**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pusillanimous)"*. But if you follow that Merriam-Webster link you'll find this list of antonyms for ***pusillanimous***...

> *brave, courageous, daring, dauntless, doughty, fearless, gallant, greathearted, gutsy, hardy, heroic (also heroical), intrepid, lionhearted, stalwart, stout, stouthearted, valiant, valorous*

***Magnanimous*** doesn't appear in that list - nor would I expect it to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Magnanimity is all that.

Comment: Does it even include military, diplomatic and scientific skills or talents? Since magnanimity is the "greatness of mind and heart"? Like Alexander the Great would be an epitome of magnanimity, being courageous, willing to overlook (eg insult from Diogenes) insightful, and possessing military and diplomatic prowess? Is magnanimity able to encompass all qualities of Alexander the Great?

Comment: In my humble opinion: no.